# Конвертация левостороннего базиса в кватернион

Tags: математика, разработка-игр, матрицы

Помогите пожалуйста построить кватернион из левостороннего базиса. [Я нашел решение для правосторонней системы,](https://d3cw3dd2w32x2b.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/matrix-to-quat.pdf) но там нет объяснения, как это сделать для левосторонней.

---

**Как я определил базис:**

- Левосторонний
- Ось вверх: Y
- Ось правая: X
- Ось вперед: Z

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Заранее всем очень благодарен !

Comment: А решение вообще зависит от того, левосторонняя система координат или нет?

Comment: Да. Кватернион содержит ось вращения и угол поворота вокруг этой оси. Для ПСК вращение будет положительным против часовой стрелки (если смотреть из конца оси в ее начало); для ЛСК вращение будет положительным по часовой стрелки.

Comment: Тааак. А если использовать ту же самую матрицу поворота в другой системе координат (левосторонней вместо правосторонней, или наоборот), разве единственной разницей не будет как раз изменение угла поворота на противоположный? Я бы все-таки попробовал этот метод.

Comment: На первый взгляд все работает, большое спасибо =)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat не хотите оформить как ответ?

Comment: @AntonMenshov Давайте лучше вы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Огромная благодарность [@HolyBlackCat](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1152893/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd/1177789#comment2000876_1152893)

Для ПСК и ЛСК формулы абсолютно идентичны.
Допустим у нас есть ориентация в виде 3х3 матрицы:

```
Matrix<3,3> orientation
{
    X.x, Y.x, Z.x,
    X.y, Y.y, Z.y,
    X.z, Y.z, Z.z
};
```

Элементы этой матрицы имеют одни и те же значения как в ЛСК, так и в ПСК.
Элементы кватерниона, который будет построен из этой матрицы, будут иметь одни и те же значения как в ЛСК, так и в ПСК. Это было проверено с помощью двух независимых сторонних SDK:
**UnrealEngine** (ЛСК) и **HudiniFX** (ПСК).